# Graphql: Multiple Apollo Servers and Merged Results

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I've been looking in to Graphql over the last few days whilst doing some tech investigation for a new project.

Effectively I have multiple web sites which have a common Rest API implementation and schemas.

Ideally I'd like to be able to query them independently to get things like customers and orders for each site, but I'd also like to be able to consolidate the results in to a single endpoint.

As a proof of concept I've created an Apollo Server with a RestDataSource to provide a Graphql endpoint to wrap the Rest API.

I guess what I'm struggling to get my head around is how to scale this out to multiple sites and the best application architecture.

Should I create an individual Apollo Server for each site i.e

```
http://localhost/site1:4000
http://localhost/site2:4000
http://localhost/global:4000
```

Within the app would I then create:

```
/server/site1/
/server/site2/
/server/global
/common/typedefs
/common/resolvers
```

Having multiple servers configs feels as thought there is a fair bit of duplicated effort.

Any thoughts?

Equally any advice on merging the endpoints together would be greatly appreciated

Current code looks like this:

```
    //pull in the env configuration
    require('dotenv').config();
    
    //pull in application specific configuration
    var config = require('./config.json');
    
    //Apollo Server and GraphQL
    const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server');
    var { graphql, buildSchema } = require('graphql');
    
    //Prospect API
    const { ProspectAPI } = require('./prospectapi');
    
    //Define the GraphQL schema for prospects
    const typeDefs = gql`
      type Prospect {
        date_created_gmt: String
        first_name: String
        last_name: String
        email: String
        billing: Address
        meta_data: [Metadata]
      }
    
      type Address { 
        address1: String
        address2: String
        city: String
        postcode: String
        country: String
        state: String
        phone: String
      }
    
      type Metadata {
        id: String
        key: String
        value: String
      }
    
      type Query {
        prospectByEmail(email: String!): [Prospect]
        prospectByID(id: String!): Prospect
        latestProspects: [Prospect]
      }
    
    `;
    
    //define the resolvers
    const resolvers = {
        Query: {
          prospectByEmail: async (_, { email }, { dataSources }) => {
            return dataSources.prospectAPI.getProspectByEmail(email);
          },
          prospectByID: async (_, { id }, { dataSources }) => {
            return dataSources.prospectAPI.getProspectByID(id);
          },
          latestProspects: async (_, __, { dataSources }) => {
    
            return dataSources.prospectAPI.getLatestProspects();
    
          },
        },
      };
    
    
    //instantiate the apollo server
    const server = new ApolloServer({
      cors: true,
      typeDefs,
      resolvers,
      dataSources: () => {
        return {
          prospectAPI: new ProspectAPI(config.endpoint, config.user, config.pass)    
        };
      },
    });
    
    // The `listen` method launches a web server.
    server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
        console.log(`  Server ready at ${url}`);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit more Google Foo leads me to Apollo Federation and sub graphs which looks like it will do the trick